# Need some help writing an EMPTY_OR macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to code a macro called `EMPTY_OR`, which will return the first argument, but if it's empty, it will return the second one.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

#define EMPTY_OR(x, y) ( (sizeof(#x) > sizeof("")) ? (x) : (y) )

#define TEST(x, y) EMPTY_OR(y, x)

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int four = TEST(4, );
    int eight = TEST(4, 8);
    cout << "four: " << four << endl;
    cout << "eight: " << eight << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's close, but it doesn't work because the first line of the `main` function expands to the following:

```
( (sizeof("") > sizeof("")) ? () : (4) )
```

The condition is never true, so `()` is never evaluated. I shouldn't care about it, but the compiler does, and it shows an error.

How can I solve it with the most straightforward and standard-compliant (or at least MSVC-compliant) way?

Comment: What type of argument(s) does it need to handle?

Comment: Only numeric, as in the example.

Comment: Seems a bit like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do? (Have you tried `(strlen(#x) > 0)? ...`?)

Comment: The `sizeof` is not the problem, `()` is. See the expanded line. What am I trying to do? I'm trying to write a macro with a number of numeric arguments, where an empty argument will mean the value of the previous one. i.e. `FOO(1, , 3)` will mean `FOO(1, 1, 3)`. Yes, it's hackish and bad design, but what I'm dealing with requires this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, I'd remove the sizeof and just check if the first character in the string is `\0`;

```c
#define EMPTY_OR(x, y) ( #x[0] ? (x+0) : (y) )
```

Comment: But `x` and `y` aren't strings in the OP's test-case.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth `#x` converts x to a string, if the parameter is empty, just to `""`. Seems to match his sample code, this returns `four: 4, eight: 8` with that.

Comment: Ah, I misread this.  On a second look, this does seem reasonable (relies on `+0` being valid syntax on its own)!

Comment: Looks good, `#x[0]` is indeed a nice idea. I thought about `+0` myself, but can't it break stuff? I mean the kind of stuff with macros and operator precedence.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that `x` must support addition with an integer. If, for example, you did `TEST("abc"s, "def"s)`, it would barf at doing `std::string + int`.

Comment: Another drawback I see is that the following will compile: `EMPTY_OR(1==, 2)`, `EMPTY_OR(1-, 2)`. Not critical, but less than ideal. I'll see if there are other suggestions before marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution adapted from [this article](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/) and without Boost that works on anything that I can think of that you can pass:

```
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_(a, b)
#define CAT_(a, b) a##b

#define IF(cond, t, f) CAT(IF_, cond)(t, f)
#define IF_1(t, f) t
#define IF_0(t, f) f

#define COMMA(x) ,

#define ARG3(a, b, c, ...) c
#define HAS_COMMA(x) ARG3(x, 1, 0,)

#define EMPTY(x) EMPTY_(HAS_COMMA(COMMA x ()))

#define EMPTY_(x) HAS_COMMA(CAT(EMPTY_, x))
#define EMPTY_1 ,

#define EMPTY_OR(x, y) IF(EMPTY(x), y, x)
#define TEST(x, y) EMPTY_OR(y, x)


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t = TEST(1==, ) 1;
    int f = TEST(1==, 0==) 1;
    cout << "t: " << t << endl;
    cout << "f: " << f << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could work if the project would depend on boost already, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Paul, I've updated the answer to work on (I hope) every type of argument and to not use Boost.

Comment: It's quite complicated, and I don't see how it's better than Joachim's answer. I don't need complicated expressions such as the one in your sample, only numeric values. And your example still accepts incorrect expressions such as: `int f = TEST(1==, 0);`.

Comment: @Paul, Ah, I misread your comment as you wanting to be able to use those expressions. My bad. Indeed if you don't need anything but integers, this is overkill, but I'll leave it up in case anyone finds it helpful in the future.